# Can iPhone API access Mail/Messages/etc.?

Tags: iphone, email, sms

My iPhone App needs to access messages (SMS), email and push events on apps. Is it possible with API?

Important enough - my app does not need to *capture* them in the background (I know this is impossible), but just when it's launched being able to load/aggregate/analyze them (for specific search/analytical purposes).

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible on the current iPhone OS version (3.1).

Comment: Does this still hold for iOS 4.3?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with the current APIs. Not allowed by Apple.